# GAE ndb future.done() never returns true

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

The following recursive function loops infinitely because f.done() never returns true. Why does .done() never return true?

```
        def check(f):
            if f.done():
                logging.info(f.get_result())
            else:
                check(f)

        f = ndb.Key(Entity, 'id').get_async()
        #loops forever
        check(f)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that is to make the future "done" will never get a chance to run because you never yield from the task or call get_result() or wait() on anything.

NDB's async processing doesn't use threads -- it interleaves code in a single thread and only switches between *tasks* when certain calls are made, such as wait(), get_result(), or yield .

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem possible that this will loop forever. At most, it will loop for **60 seconds**, which is the default wait time argument for the `get_async` method.

Also, unless this is a fairly simple example to illustrate a point, your recursion is not necessary. The `get_result` method will do all that for you, wrap it in a `try - except` and catch the exception if the query didn't succeed.

> get_result() -
>   Waits if necessary; then returns the result or raises the exception.

Comment: It is a simple example to illustrate a point. I still do not understand why f.done() never returns True. Obviously putting in a wait() or a get_result() will get the result and done will return True. But why do I need to call either of those before .done() returns True? Doesn't this moot the point of .done()?